# Mediterranean Sea name in Old Latin

Tags: place-names, old-latin

It is well known that the Romans referred to the Mediterranean Sea as `mare nostrum`, especially after the Punic Wars when they had claimed Iberia, Northern Africa, Sicily, etc.

But what did they call it *before* the Punic Wars?  For instance, what would they have called the Mediterranean during, say, the Samnite wars?  What about during the Latin wars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best reference for such questions is Brills’s New Pauly.

[Eckart Olshausen](http://www.uni-stuttgart.de/hi/emeriti/olshausen/) (Universität Stuttgart), the author of the book *Einführung in die Historische Geographie der Alten Welt* (1991), writes that  “[a]s a term of Roman imperialism **Mare Nostrum** first occurs in Caes. B Gall. 5,1,2, whereas mare mediterraneum is a medieval word formation (cf. Isid. Orig. 13,6,1)” ([Olshausen, 2006](http://brillonline.nl/entries/brill-s-new-pauly/mare-nostrum-e723320); emphasis mine - Alex B.). *Mare internum* seems to be the most common choice in [the Historical Atlas of the Ancient World](http://brillonline.nl/browse/brill-s-new-pauly-supplements-i-3).

Olshausen also mentions, besides the above-mentioned *mare nostrum*, some other possible variants, *mare internum* and *mare intestinum* (Plin. HN 2,173 and Flor. 2,13,293).

*The Barrington Atlas of the Greek and Roman World* similarly adopts “Internum Mare.”

Answer (score 6):

Cicero (Att. 8,3) and Pliny (3. 5. 6) each refer to *mare superum*.

Lemprière's Classical Dictionary, which often has a wealth of detail on such topics, has nothing of direct use, but from its rather obscure information I deduce that the name *Tyrrhenum Mare* is reliably old: for example, Tyrrheus was the keeper of flocks for king Latinus, while Tyrrhenus, son of a king of Lydia, having come to Italy, first had what eventually became Etruria named after him.